# unix timestamp conversion results not accurate php

Tags: php

I am trying to convert a unix timestamp into readable text. The timestamp is stored in a database and shown in a table. The problem is the results are not accurate.

---

**Code:**

```
<td>'.date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($row['expire'])).'</td>
```

---

**database:**

[image]

---

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @Evan Mulawski i update my question to show expire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

- Remove the `strtotime` call, since you already have the timestamp as a number, OR
- Change the database field to TIMESTAMP.